# loop array (columns) and save results on new array

Tags: php, arrays, charts

I'm using ChartJS to make an stepped line graph but I'm having some issues while sending the data to my graph.

This is the structure of my data:

```
{ 
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "rec3bFzlHuDdId1rW",
            "fields": {
                "RAMPA": "1",
                "VIAJE": [
                    "recDIax2GkKfVs4G0"
                ],
                "ACTUALIZACION": [
                    "recuL8WNpXtdhrtyU",
                    "rec3noGgAthIDtyYS"
                ],
                "VIAJE 2": [
                    "recDIax2GkKfVs4G0",
                    "recqV0qm47g0ZiDk4"
                ],
                "DT": [
                    "98249184"
                ],
                "LIN": [
                    445
                ],
                "CITA DE ENRRAMPE": [
                    "2020-11-07T17:48:00.000Z"
                ],
                "TIMEPO DE USO SEMANA": 88920,
                "TIEMPO DE DESUSO SEMANA": 484080,
                "USOS SEMANA": 1,
                "SALIDA DE CARGA": [
                    "2020-11-08T02:00:00.000Z"
                ],
                "Field 14": [
                    "98249184",
                    "6546526534"
                ],
                "ENRRAMPE": [
                    "ENRRAMPE TARDIO"
                ],
                "ENRRAMPES TARDIOS DIA": 1,
                "VALOR1HISTORICO": [
                    1,
                    0
                ],
                "VALOR2": [
                    "15:10",
                    "15:51"
                ]
            },
            "createdTime": "2020-10-23T18:43:45.000Z"
        },
}
```

so far I can loop through it using this piece of code:

```
foreach($airtable_response['records'] as $key => $record)
{
  $string.= $record['fields']['VALOR2'][0] . ', ';
  $labels.= '"' . $record['fields']['VALOR1HISTORICO'][0] . '", ';
}

$data = trim($string, ",");
$labels = trim($labels, ",");
```

But what I need to get is only the data stored per register example from VALOR2 which only has two values, get the values "15:10" and "15:51" and send those n values stored there to my new array so they can be accepted by the graph.

EDIT:
when I echo the variable $labels and $data I get these values

$labels
15:10, 15:10, 15:10, 15:10, 15:10, 15:10, 13:15, 15:10,

$data
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",

but these are the first values from 8 records what I want is to only bring

labels
15:10, 15:51

data
1, 0

which belong to one record each one and so on

this is part of the full structure of my data: (this is one record)

```
       "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
        1,
        0
        ],
        "VALOR2":[
        "15:10",
        "15:51"
        ]
    },
       (this is one record)

    "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
    1
    ],
    "VALOR2":[
    "15:10"
    ]
     (this is one record)
    "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
    1
    ],
    "VALOR2":[
    "15:10"
    ]
     (this is one record)
    "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
    1
    ],
    "VALOR2":[
    "15:10"
    ]
     (this is one record)
    "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
    1
    ],
    "VALOR2":[
    "15:10"
    ]
 (this is one record)
    "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
    1
    ],
    "VALOR2":[
    "15:10"
    ]
 (this is one record)
  

      "VALOR1HISTORICO":[
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1
        ],
        "VALOR2":[
        "13:15",
        "13:16",
        "15:10",
        "12:20",
        "12:20",
        "12:20",
        "12:21"
        ]
```

the format that brings me the for each loop is:

```
15:10,15:51,15:10,,15:10,,15:10,,15:10,,15:10,,13:15,13:16,15:10,
```

which I would like to bring is

```
$labels ["15:10","15:51"], 
$data[1,0]
```

then loop again and bring the another data for other record

```
  $labels ["15:10"], 
    $data["1"]
```

once again other arrays which belong to another record

```
 $labels ["15:10""], 
    $data["1"]
```

which this data I'm expecting to generate one graph per $label,$data...

This is the ChatJS which will receive every data:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m8 offset-m2 s12" style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <div class="airtable">                  
                    <canvas height="200" id="myChart2" width="200"></canvas>
                    <script>
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2");
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels:[<?php echo $labels; ?>],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: ' Tiempos de traslado ',
                                data: [<?php echo $data; ?>],
                                 steppedLine:true,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                    
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide with an example input and the expected output of it?

Comment: is there any method to access 'VALOR1HISTORICO' and 'VALOR2' and those values save into new array ? Im trying to get two new arrays from those values

Comment: You code is already accessing VALOR1HISTORICO and VALOR2. You can just append them to your new array, right? What is your difficulty?

Comment: And should the "new array" look like?

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing the strings too early. It's harder to parse and manipulate a string than to manipulate an array. You should first aggregate your data into an intermediate array format. Since the value are stored within a sub-array in the key, you can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge) to merge the values:

```php
$valor2s = [];
$valor1historico = [];
foreach($airtable_response['records'] as $key => $record) {
  array_merge($valor2s, $record['fields']['VALOR2'][0]);
  array_merge($valor1historicos, '"' . $record['fields']['VALOR1HISTORICO'][0] . '"');
}
```

If I read you correctly, you wants the unique values of VALOR2 and VALOR1HISTORICO. You can use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique) to clean up the 2 arrays:

```php
$valor2s_unique = array_unique($valor2s);
$valor1historicos_unique = array_unique($valor1historicos);
```

Then you can join the arrays to a string of comma separated list with [implode](https://www.php.net/implode):

```php
$data = implode(', ', $valor2s_unique);
$labels = implode(', ', $valor1historicos_unique);
```

Given the data you demonstrated, you should get these variables:

```
15:10, 13:15
"1", "0"
```

Comment: thanks but this info is to build a stepped line chart so repeated values are allowed ,it seems i didnt explain myself each record have diferent values on these case hours and 1 and 0 wich work like a flag every register (event) must have their own graph that's why i need to build an array for each register wich have multiple values separated by ','

Comment: "VALOR1HISTORICO": [
                    1,
                    0
                ],
                "VALOR2": [
                    "15:10",
                    "15:51"
                ] these are two records wich on each record i must to bring two arrays,one per record, to build their graph one for $labels and one fro $data

Comment: Please mock up the expected result array(s) in proper php code format. I couldn't really understand your explanation to the expected result.

Comment: The best way to explain your issue is to mock up both the input and output in proper php code.

Comment: thank you i have edited once again ... I dont even know if its possible to achieve what im trying to do

Comment: Do you only need to first item in `VALOR2` and `VALOR1HISTORICO` of each record?

Comment: Man, you really need to properly learn either PHP or JSON. It's really hard to read your ad-hoc data representation.

Comment: no that [0] index was because when I tried to print the values they only bring me ARRAY but what i need to achieve is was I explained, no first item ,but I need every item inside VALOR2 and VALOR1HISTORICO  to build my array

Comment: Do you want your `$labels` and `$data` to be string or array? Also, where are you going to consume your `$labels` and `$data` (since you seems to want to overwrite / redeclare them on each iteration of `foreach`)?

Comment: for now i only want to bring the data I need wich is $labels ["15:10","15:51"], 
$data[1,0] , for example for each record ,I think for each is giving me issues too since it is indeed overwriting every value Im going to use ChartJs so draw a graph for every single record

Comment: Can you explain what you actually need to do as a whole? I suppose you'll use some of these output to generate javascript call to chartJS, right? Can you demonstrate the javascript that you need to run?

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XqrqRj something similar to this but using php and labels ,data dynamic too the chart that will receive the data I will post the code

Comment: If you plan to do this project in long term, please consider to learn PHP and Javascript. Your question implies you have serious issue understanding very basic syntax in PHP. Every learner, including me, have been there. But you need to put more effort in understanding the basics.